# AJAX request after Rails function returns data

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

Is there a way in Rails for me to make an AJAX request and send data to my JS after I run a function in my model and it returns data to me?

ex:

```
def some_function
    example = Model.some_function
    # after the function returns data, i want to send data to JS via ajax
end
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, ajax is not about the server sending data to the client but the client fetching data to the server.

Comment: I think there is no way except sending AJAX request to load that data.Here is the workaround that could solve your problem.On page load you send a AJAX request and get the data from the server and use them as you wish to.
    $(document).ready(function(){
$.ajax({ url: "<%= your_path %>",
        context: document.body,
        success: function(response){
           yourData = response.data
        }});
}); 

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Yes, [WebSockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) are a way of creating duplex communication between the client and server. In rails this is done with [ActionCable](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_cable_overview.html). However this is way to broad for a SO question. Either that that or by using polling.